# FireDac not insert "&" symbol into SQLITE varchar

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

We have table1 in SQLITE database.

```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (id int PRIMARY KEY ,name nvarchar );
```

After using in DELPHI XE3 Firedac ADQuery SQL command

```
  INSERT INTO table1 (id,name)  VALUES (1,'&Text To &Insert.')
```

we have in column name only "To ." All the text starting with & symbol until any punctuation symbol is not copied!
there are 2 exceptions: 
    Texts followed by && or \& are being copied correctly.
The same command in Sqlite Expert Personal app works OK.

Is it Firedac bug? And How Copy texts into database containing & symbol using Firedac?
(texts are HTML documents containing many "&" symbols)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQLite or FireDAC. You text is not valid HTML.

Comment: This error I noticed when after inserting valid html document instead of line "<P>&nbsp;</P>" there was "<P>;</P>" in the column "name".

Comment: Forget about html. In given example after inserting string "&Text To &Insert." we have in column name only "To .": All the text starting with & symbol until any punctuation symbol or space is not copied!

Comment: Look up how entities in HTML (SGML) work.

Comment: Dear CL. Forget about HTML. Let's talk about the string "&Text To &Insert.". After inserting with Firedac ADQUERY into field name, we have there only "To ." . The same command in Sqlite Expert Personal app, which I suppose does not use Firedac, Inserts the given string correctly.

Comment: I can send You an application example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/TFDQuery,_TFDStoredProc_and_TFDUpdateSQL_Questions):

> **Q8: My query containing the '&', '!' characters fails to execute correctly. What is wrong?**
>
> […] '&' specifies the beginning of a macro variable. […] If you do not use macros, then set `ResourceOptions.MacroCreate` and `MacroExpand` to `False`.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. And why they not set the default value of these parameters to False??